# Use JavaMail (mail.jar) without dependency on Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I want to remove the Java EE dependency from my codebase so that my program is much more portable and easier for "average joe" to use. I really would like to not use the `mail.jar` since that relies on a Java EE container (JBoss, Tomcat, etc). I'd also like to not rely on something that simply wraps mail.jar (apache commons-email) since that still depends on Java EE.

I have seen some stuff online that hints at using sockets in Java SE, however the examples I found commentors posted that they did not work or were broken.

Since Java EE is built on Java SE, surely Java SE can send email without Java EE?

How can I accomplish this? (Want to send through Gmail for now, but future support of other SMTP services such as Exchange, Zimbra would be great).

Comment: You don't need a container to send email.

Comment: Where did you learn using JavaMail so that you ended up with this completely incorrect statement? There's a download link in their own (further excellent!) FAQ: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html -- check the 2nd point *"How do I get an implementation of the JavaMail API?"*

Comment: How do you know mail.jar has a dependency on the Java EE container? Because the reference implementation of Oracle hasn't. See [JavaMail 1.4.7 MVNrepository entry](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4.7) and its [pom file](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.4.7/mail-1.4.7.pom) : no external dependencies!

Comment: I see now. I have always built my software from within Eclipse, and followed some tutorial to install JBoss in Eclipse and add those Java EE (5) libraries to my build path. So when I moved my code to a continuous integration server, the build failed because it needed the Java EE (mail.jar) file. I incorrectly understood this to mean I needed all of Java EE just to compile my sending email classes. I have downloaded mail.jar (JavaMail API) and added that to my build path replacing the Java EE 5 libs, works like a charm in Eclipse, we'll see if the CI server concurs. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaMail API is available as an optional package for use with Java SE platform and is also included in the Java EE platform.
[Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail-138606.html)

Comment: So JavaMail does not require Java EE to function (and therefore does not require a container such as JBoss, Tomcat, etc)? Is this the same with Apache commons-email.jar ?

Comment: @SnakeDoc commons-email also doesn't need JaveEE, it just needs javamail. Maybe you are confused by the fact that JavaMail is **also** part of JavaEE

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Bingo, I think that is what was confusing me... the Oracle site would say something along the lines of "JavaMail API is integrated into Java EE, but is also an add on for Java SE", leading me to believe it needed Java EE to work. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So it seems that commons-email is just a wrapper for JavaMail, but allows you to more simply use the library?

Comment: @SnakeDoc Yes, commons-email wraps JavaMail to simplify the interface.